# Stop and start Unix daemon in C

Tags: c, unix, command-line, daemon

I'm trying to develop a daemon (unix plateforme) with this capabilities(command line):

```
user@unixbox>myDaemon start // This start the daemon
user@unixbox>myDaemon stop // This stop the daemon
user@unixbox>myDaemon show // This will show some stuff that the daemon is doing
```

If you know any documentation or ideas on how this can be implemented. please let me know :).

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is super vague. Are those intended to be command line arguments to the daemon that is written in C, or does a C program need to run the myDaemon with those arguments?

Comment: @Tom : Thanks, i wrote a simple daemon in c and i want to add this command line capabilities to interact with it (like mysqld daemon for example)

Answer (score 2):

This is usually done by delivering signals to the daemon process.

You have to choose a particular signal to respond to in your daemon (`SIGTERM`, `SIGQUIT`, `SIGSTOP`, etc.) by installing a handler that is invoked each time the process receives the signal.

From the shell you can send signals to a process using the `kill(1)` command.

Note that a graceful daemon stop may be quite tricky if you have active clients/connections/jobs. Normally you should stop receiving new ones and wait until the last one is finished.

Comment: Thanks, i can understand for start and stop, but how to implement a custom command like : myDaemon show (which show some stuff for example)

Comment: There are the signals `SIGUSR1` and `SIGUSR2` that are intended for application-specific needs.

Comment: Is this the right way that daemons use to implement command-line interaction? thanks.

Comment: If you really want "interaction", the best way would be to have a Unix domain socket and a dedicated thread in your daemon that listens on it.

Comment: Ok thanks, so i implement a unix domain socket server inside my daemon, but how can i interact with it from the command line (i need a client to do this not the same command as the daemon name? did you understand what i mean?)

Comment: From the command line you may use the utilities `netcat` or `nc` to write data to the socket (they are originally intended for TCP/IP, but I think they should support Unix sockets as well).

Comment: It's not the solution of my problem, how can i do this commend for example : myDaemon show? i don't want to use netcat or other, i just want to know how other daemons like mysqld and httpd and others handle command-line. Thanks.